# How to Power Query Windows folder-share security/access permissions?

Tags: excel, active-directory, file-permissions, fileshare, powerquery

We have a folder on a shared-drive which contains many subfolders containing live Excel-based reports. These reports should only be available to particular users and groups, as managed through Active Directory. To ensure our security model is solid, I'd like to enable non-admin users to view the access permissions, through Excel.

Can we use Power Query to display the accessibility (read/write etc.) of each of these subfolders in Excel?

The closest I have seen so far is under: 
PowerQuery > From File > From Folder > Select folder > Expand 'Attributes' column for a record.

But the detail I require is not available here.
Can it be done with PQ? Perhaps we need to go through Active Directory querying instead?

The specific format/view on the data is flexible. So long as AD Users/Groups are mapped clearly to the explicit permissions that are permitted or denied to them.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is Active Directory querying.

Power Query doesn't have the capability to display security settings on folders.

In some programming languages you could try to open each file as the user and handle errors, but in Power Query security errors are not catchable.

If you want a program to read folder permissions, I think you'd be better-suited using a language that can directly interact with OS-level APIs.